# Store objects in an array and print it out JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, object, tostring

I've created different types of objects like object1 object2 etc. Now, how can I store these objects into an array and print that array out? The idea below does not work.

```
Buch buch = new Buch("Blablabla", "Baba Isi", "DE 1234567890", 50, 1234f); 
    System.out.println(buch.toString()); 
    //5 Objekte erstellen
    /*2*/Buch buch2 = new Buch("Blabla2", "blubb", "DE 5461563259", 50, 1234f); 
    System.out.println(buch2.toString()); 
    /*3*/Buch buch3 = new Buch("Check this out", "oke", "DE 67892011789", 50, 1234f); 
    System.out.println(buch3.toString()); 
    /*4*/Buch buch4 = new Buch("Got ya", "catch ya", "DE 678198771890", 50, 1234f); 
    System.out.println(buch4.toString()); 
    /*5*/Buch buch5 = new Buch("IDK", "IDK2", "DE 47740710974691", 50, 1234f); 
    System.out.println(buch5.toString()); 

    Buch[] arr = new Buch[5]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        arr[i] = new Buch(); 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){      //toString method exists an it works
        System.out.println(arr[i].toString()); 
    }
```

The output:

Titel: Ein Mann ein Wort   Autor: Baba Isi   ISBN: DE 1234567890   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: Wanna smash   Autor: smash it   ISBN: DE 5461563259   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: Smash Me   Autor: oke   ISBN: DE 67892011789   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: Got ya   Autor: catch ya   ISBN: DE 678198771890   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: IDK   Autor: IDK2   ISBN: DE 47740710974691   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: IDK   Autor: IDK2   ISBN: DE 47740710974691   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: IDK   Autor: IDK2   ISBN: DE 47740710974691   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: IDK   Autor: IDK2   ISBN: DE 47740710974691   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: IDK   Autor: IDK2   ISBN: DE 47740710974691   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Titel: IDK   Autor: IDK2   ISBN: DE 47740710974691   Seitenzahl: 50   Preis:    1234.0

Comment: Your code should work. What error do you get ?

Comment: I have had an error because i forgot the ";" in the for loop to print out the array. Now I fixed it an my Code has the output:

Comment: I have a hunch that your fields are all declared `static`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have gave data to objects in constructor. Indeed, when you are creating new array, you are generating new objects which do not contain your strings.

To resolve that, you can give the arguments of objects in another function and call that function for each one of array item after generation such as following:

```
        Buch[] arr = new Buch[5]; 
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            arr[i] = new Buch(); 
        }

        arr[0].fill("Blablabla", "Baba Isi", "DE 1234567890", 50, 1234f); 
        arr[1].fill("Blabla2", "blubb", "DE 5461563259", 50, 1234f); 
        arr[2].fill("Check this out", "oke", "DE 67892011789", 50, 1234f); 
        arr[3].fill("Got ya", "catch ya", "DE 678198771890", 50, 1234f); 
        arr[4].fill("IDK", "IDK2", "DE 47740710974691", 50, 1234f);


        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){      //toString method exists an it works
            System.out.println(arr[i].toString()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the for loop by something like that :

```
    Buch[] arr = { buch, buch2, buch3, buch4, buch5 };
```